# How to cancel a coroutine if already running?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I'm looking for filter a list on user input (SearchView)

```
fun onQuery(query: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Default) {
            val personsFound = persons.filter { person ->
                        person.nom.contains(query) || person.prenom.contains(query)
            }
            withContext(Main) { _items.value = personsFound }
        }
    }
```

If the user tap quickly on the keyboard the function will be called many times and sometimes before the previous call is finished. So I'm looking to stop the coroutine if a new call is done and the coroutine is already running. How can I achieved this please ?

What I tried :

```
fun onQuery(query: String) {
        
        val job = viewModelScope.launch(Default) {
            val personsFound = persons.filter { person ->
                person.nom.contains(query) || person.prenom.contains(query)
            }
            withContext(Main) { _items.value = personsFound }
        }
        
        if (job.isActive) job.cancel()
        
        job.start()
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is supposed to be only one instance of that `job` running, then I would try taking a reference to it outside of that code block and storing it as a private variable inside the class in which the method `onQuery` operates:

```kotlin
private var job: Job? = null

...

fun onQuery(query: String) {
    job?.run { if (isActive) cancel() }

    job = viewModelScope.launch(Default) {
        val personsFound = persons.filter { person ->
            person.nom.contains(query) || person.prenom.contains(query)
        }
        withContext(Main) { _items.value = personsFound }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You'd need to initialise `job` as null though (since there isn't one in the beginning) and null-check it with `job?.run { if (isActive) cancel() }`. Or use `lateinit` and `::job.isInitialized` but I feel like *null* is cleaner here!

Comment: Oh yes, You're right! I've missed that point. I've edited the answer.

Comment: `job?.cancel()` is a better practice (and easier to read), because you might miss the case in which the underlying `Job` is started lazily, and is in the New state, where `isActive` return false. You can check the `Job` documentation to find out more